# Oracle: how to get the age with the year of birth

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that I need to return the: NIC , name and age of the female gender of people aged 10 to 15 years, or who interpreted
at least one character in a program and were born before 2000. Note: You can use builders of join

the tables are :

**people** -> nic ; name ; gender  ; year of birth
 **interpret** ->  people ; programm ; character

So for this NIC, name and age of the female gender of people aged 10 to 15 years I use

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')-p1.birth as age , p.nic , p.name
FROM people p
WHERE (p.gender ='F')
AND ( SELECT to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')-p1.birth as age
  FROM people p1
 WHERE (p1.age BETWEEN 10 AND 15);
```

or who interpreted
at least one character in a program and were born before 2000

```
UNION
Select *
From interpret i , people p1
Where (i.people = p1.nic)
And(p1.character is not null)
and (p1 < 2000);
```

But especially on the first peace of code it gives me 2 main errors
in this `AND ( SELECT to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')-p1.birth as age`
and in this  `WHERE (p1.age BETWEEN 10 AND 15);`

Comment: try to_number() instead of to_char()

Comment: You are subtracting a `date` from a `string` - not a very sensible thing to do. If you want the difference in days between two `date`s, just subtract them: `sysdate -  p1.birth`. @blckbird: `to_number()` on a `date` would be wrong as well

Comment: Do you want something like this at the second select ? and p1.birth < 2000

Comment: What are the errors exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're missing a closing parentheses.

try this code

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')-p1.birth as age , p.nic , p.name
FROM people p
WHERE (p.gender ='F')
AND p1.birth ( SELECT to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')-p1.birth as age
  FROM people p1
 WHERE (p1.age BETWEEN 10 AND 15));
```